# How does numpy order array slice indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I have an np.array `data` of shape (28,8,20), and I only need certain entries from it, so I'm taking a slice:

```
In [41]: index = np.array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 17, 18, 19])
In [42]: extract = data[:,:,index]
In [43]: extract.shape
Out[43]: (28, 8, 10)
```

So far so good, everything as it should be. But now I wand to look at just the first two entries on the last index for the first line:

```
In [45]: extract[0,:,np.array([0,1])].shape
Out[45]: (2, 8)
```

Wait, that should be (8,2). It switched the indices around, even though it did not when I sliced the last time! According to my understanding, the following should act the same way:

```
In [46]: extract[0,:,:2].shape
Out[46]: (8, 2)
```

... but it gives me exactly what I wanted! As long as I have a 3D-array, though, both methods seem to be equivalent:

```
In [47]: extract[:,:,np.array([0,1])].shape
Out[47]: (28, 8, 2)

In [48]: extract[:,:,:2].shape
Out[48]: (28, 8, 2)
```

So what do I do if I want not just the first two entries but an irregular list? I could of course transpose the matrix after the operation but this seems very counter-intuitive.
A better solution to my problem is this (though there might be a more elegant one):

```
In [64]: extract[0][:,[0,1]].shape
Out[64]: (8, 2)
```

Which brings us to the actual

### question:

I wonder what the reason for this behaviour is? Whoever decided that this is how it should work probably knew more about programming than I do and thought that this is consistent in some way that I am entirely missing. And I will likely keep hitting my head on this unless I have a way to make sense of it.

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for advanced indexing (using arrays as indices) acknowledge that the behavior "can be somewhat mind-boggling to understand".  I dare not try to fully grasp the intricacies of this sort of indexing.  Suffice it to say that using an array instead of a slice (i.e., `[0, 1]` instead of `:2`) triggers a different type of indexing behavior, and combining different sorts of indices (single integers, slices, arrays) can quickly take you into strange territory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of (advanced) partial indexing.  There are 2 indexed arrays, and 1 slice

> If the indexing subspaces are separated (by slice objects), then the broadcasted indexing space is first, followed by the sliced subspace of x.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

The advanced indexing example notes, when the `ind_1`, `ind_2` broadcastable subspace is `shape (2,3,4)` that:

> However, x[:,ind_1,:,ind_2] has shape (2,3,4,10,30,50) because there is no unambiguous place to drop in the indexing subspace, thus it is tacked-on to the beginning. It is always possible to use .transpose() to move the subspace anywhere desired.

In other words, this indexing is not the same as `x[:, ind_1][[:,ind_2]`.  The 2 arrays operate jointly to define a `(2,3,4)` subspace.

In your example, `extract[0,:,np.array([0,1])]` is understood to mean, select a `(2,)` subspace (the [0] and [0,1] act jointly, not sequentially), and combine that in some way with the middle dimension.

A more elaborate example would be `extract[[1,0],:,[[0,1],[1,0]]]`, which produces a `(2,2,8)` array.  This is a `(2,2)` subspace of the 1st and last dimensions, plus the middle one.  On the other hand, `X[[1,0]][:,:,[[0,1],[1,0]]]` produces a `(2,8,2,2)`, selecting from the 1st and last dimensions separately.

The key difference is whether the indexed selections operate sequential or jointly.  The `[...][...] syntax is already available to operate sequentially.  Advanced indexing gives you a way indexing jointly.

Comment: If I understand correctly then the `0` in my code will be treated as a one-item list, so the two `lists` will be broadcast together (which gives a 1x2 array), and thus the index moves to the front.

Comment: ... because there's no "unambiguous" other place  to put it. And the whole idea of using broadcasting at all is not slicing as such but indexing, where I could put arbitrary arrays in the indices and get all sorts of permutations of the original array's content -- that seems to make sense, although it would seem more consequent to drop the index in first place for `[:,:,[0,1]]`, as well.

Comment: Which means I should consequently use separate indices (`[...][...]`) to make my intention unambiguous -- thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're right, that's weird. I can only hazard a guess here. I think it's related to the fact that `a[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]].shape` is `(2,)` rather than `(2,2,2)` and that `a[0,1,[0,1,2]]` really means `a[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,2]]` which evaluates to `array([a[0,1,0],a[0,1,1],a[0,1,2]])`. That is, you step through lists-as-indices for each dimension in parallel, with length-one lists and scalars being broadcast to match the longest.

Conceptually, that would make your `extract[0,:,[0,1]]` equivalent to `extract[[0,0],[slice(None),slice(None)],[0,1]]` (that syntax isn't accepted if you specify it manually, though). After stepping through the indices, that would evaluate to `array([extract[0,slice(None),0],extract[0,slice(None),1])`. Each of the inner extracts evaluate to a shape `(8,)` array, so the full result is shape `(2,8)`.

So to conclude I think it is a side-effect of the broadcasting that is done to make all the dimensions have an index list of the same length, which leads to `:` being broadcast too. That is my hypothesis, but I haven't looked at the inner workings of how `numpy` does this. Perhaps an expert will come along with a better explanation.

This hypothesis does not explain why `extract[:,:,[0,1]]` does not result in the same behavior. I would have to postulate that the case of only leading ":" being special-cased to avoid participating in the list index logic.