# Combining slicing and broadcasted indexing for multi-dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a ND numpy array (let say for instance 3x3x3) from wich I'd like to extract a sub-array, combining slices and index arrays. For instance:

```
import numpy as np  
A = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape((3,3,3))
i0, i1, i2 = ([0,1], [0,1,2], [0,2])
ind1 = j0, j1, j2 = np.ix_(i0, i1, i2)
ind2 = (j0, slice(None), j2)
B1 = A[ind1]
B2 = A[ind2]
```

I would expect that B1 == B2, but actually, the shapes are different

```
>>> B1.shape
(2, 3, 2)
>>> B2.shape
(2, 1, 2, 3)
>>> B1
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 3,  5],
        [ 6,  8]],

       [[ 9, 11],
        [12, 14],
        [15, 17]]])
>>> B2
array([[[[ 0,  3,  6],
         [ 2,  5,  8]]],

       [[[ 9, 12, 15],
         [11, 14, 17]]]])
```

Someone understands why? Any idea of how I could get 'B1' by manipulating only 'A' and 'ind2' objects? The goal is that it would work for any nD arrays, and that I would not have to look for the shape of dimensions I want to keep entirely (hope I'm clear enough:)). Thanks!!
---EDIT---
To be clearer, I would like to have a function 'fun' such that

```
A[fun(ind2)] == B1
```

Comment: I think this is what you _don't want_: `ind2 = (i0, np.arange(A.shape[1]).reshape(-1,1), i2)`

Comment: is `B2 = select(A,"0,1;:;0,2")` good enough? I could post an answer if you want.

Comment: ideally, I prefere keeping the notation B2 = A[ind3], otherwise, it means that I have to replace every indexing in a long long program... But unfortunatly, I'm not sure my problem has an easy solution solution.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing subspaces of `ind1` are (2,),(3,),(2,), and the resulting `B` is `(2,3,2)`.  This is a simple case of advanced indexing.

`ind2` is a case of (advanced) partial indexing. There are 2 indexed arrays, and 1 slice.  The advanced indexing documentation states:

> If the indexing subspaces are separated (by slice objects), then the broadcasted indexing space is first, followed by the sliced subspace of x.

In this case advanced indexing constructs a `(2,2)` array (from the 1st and 3rd indexes), and appends the slice dimension at the end, resulting in a `(2,2,3)` array.

I explain the reasoning in more detail in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27097133/901925

A way to fix a tuple like `ind2`, is to expand each slice into an array.  I recently saw this done in `np.insert`.

```
np.arange(*ind2[1].indices(3))
```

expands `:` to `[0,1,2]`.  But the replacement has to have the right shape.

```
ind=list(ind2)
ind[1]=np.arange(*ind2[1].indices(3)).reshape(1,-1,1)
A[ind]
```

I'm leaving off the details of determining which term is a slice, its dimension, and the relevant reshape.  The goal is to reproduce `i1`.

If indices were generated by something other than `ix_`, reshaping this slice could be more difficult.  For example

```
A[np.array([0,1])[None,:,None],:,np.array([0,2])[None,None,:]] # (1,2,2,3)
A[np.array([0,1])[None,:,None],np.array([0,1,2])[:,None,None],np.array([0,2])[None,None,:]]
# (3,2,2)
```

The expanded slice has to be compatible with the other arrays under broadcasting.

Swapping axes after indexing is another option.   The logic, though, might be more complex.
But in some cases transposing might actually be simpler:

```
A[np.array([0,1])[:,None],:,np.array([0,2])[None,:]].transpose(2,0,1)
# (3,2,2)
A[np.array([0,1])[:,None],:,np.array([0,2])[None,:]].transpose(0,2,1)
# (2, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed indeed that the sliced dimension were added at the end. There is an exception though when the sliced dimension is first dimension. For instance, to get back to my example:  
ind3 = (slice(None),[[0],[1]],[[0,1]])  
B3 = A[ind3]  
Then B3.shape is (3,2,2)

Comment: In your solution, the problem I have is that you need to know the size of the sliced dimension (here 3). Here, I would prefere to keep the notation B=A[ind] where ind is defined independently from the shape of A (or more exactly from size of the dimensions that are sliced).

Comment: The two solutions that I see for know (but I'm not really satisfied) would be:
 - as suggested by @gboffi, replace each occurence of indexing B=A[ind] by a function select(A,ind) in a long long program
 - instead of declaring ndarrays, write the subclass MyNdarray, which inherit from ndarray, and overwrite the __getitem__ method so that A[ind] works as I would like it does.

Comment: Yes, my solution requires something like `A[fun(ind2, A.shape)]`.

Comment: `AxisConcatenator` in `np.lib.index_tricks` is an example of a class with a custom (and rather long) `__getitem__` method.  It's the base for convenience functions `r_` and `s_`.

Comment: Can you routinely reorder the axes of `A` so the ` advanced indexes are all next to each other.`?  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

Answer (score 0):

This is the closer I can get to your specs, I haven't been able to devise a solution that can compute the correct indices without knowing `A` (or, more precisely, its shape...).

```
import numpy as np  

def index(A, s):
    ind = []
    groups = s.split(';')
    for i, group in enumerate(groups):
        if group == ":":
            ind.append(range(A.shape[i]))
        else:
            ind.append([int(n) for n in group.split(',')])
    return np.ix_(*ind)

A = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape((3,3,3))

ind2 = index(A,"0,1;:;0,2")
print A[ind2]
```

A shorter version

```
def index2(A,s):return np.ix_(*[range(A.shape[i])if g==":"else[int(n)for n in g.split(',')]for i,g in enumerate(s.split(';'))])

ind3 = index2(A,"0,1;:;0,2")
print A[ind3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern and your answer. I gess there is indeed no solution of getting what I want without knowing the shape of A.

Comment: In my opinion, I think this is a (small) flaw (amoung many many many great stuffs) of numpy that we cannot do for instance A[[1,5],:,[1,2,4]] to slice an array, as we would do in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

In restricted indexing cases like this using `ix_`, it is possible to do the indexing in successive steps.

```
A[ind1]
```

is the same as

```
A[i1][:,i2][:,:,i3]
```

and since `i2` is the full range,

```
A[i1][...,i3]
```

If you only have `ind2` available

```
A[ind2[0].flatten()][[ind2[2].flatten()]
```

In more general contexts you have to know how `j0,j1,j2` broadcast with each other, but when they are generated by `ix_`, the relationship is simple.

I can imagine circumstances in which it would be convenient to assign `A1 = A[i1]`, followed by a variety of actions involving `A1`, including, but not limited to `A1[...,i3]`.  You have to be aware of when `A1` is a view, and when it is a copy.

Another indexing tool is `take`:

```
A.take(i0,axis=0).take(i2,axis=2)
```