# Indexing numpy multidimensional arrays depends on a slicing method

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a 3-D array. When I take a 2-D slice of it the result depends on whether it is indexed with a list or with a slice. In the first case the result is transposed. Didn't find this behaviour in the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]], [[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]])
>>> x
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],
       [[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
>>> x[0,:,[0,1]]
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
>>> x[0,:,slice(2)]
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
>>>
```

Could anyone point a rationale for this?

Comment: Oddly enough `a[0][:, [0, 1]]`  gives the same result as using slice().

Comment: Thank you,  P. Camilleri. The 2-D arrays acts completely predictable. The problem is the three and probably more dimensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297445/combining-slicing-and-broadcasted-indexing-for-multi-dimensional-numpy-arrays - an earlier attempt to explain mixed indexing.  The topic has come up before, but the trick is to find a good search term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, NumPy is following the axis numbering philosophy when it spits out the result when given a `list/tuple`-like index.

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

When you already specify the first two indices (`x[0, :, ]`), now the next question is how to extract the third dimension. Now, when you specify a tuple `(0,1)`, it first extracts the `0`th slice axis wise, so it gets `[1, 2]` since it lies in `0`th axis, next it extracts `1`st slice likewise and stacks below the already existing row `[1, 2]`.

```
[[1, 1, 1],          array([[1, 2],
 [2, 2, 2]]  =====>         [1, 2]])
```

(visualize this stacking as below (*not on top of*) the already existing row since axis-0 grows downwards)[image]

Alternatively, it is following the slicing philosophy (`start`:`stop`:`step`) when `slice(n)` is given for the index. Note that using `slice(2)` is essentially equal to `0:2` in your example. So, it extracts `[1, 1]` first, then `[2, 2]`. Note, here to how `[1, 1]` comes on top of `[2, 2]`, again following the same axis philosophy here since we didn't leave the third dimension yet. This is why this result is the transpose of the other.

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

---

Also, note that starting from 3-D arrays this consistency is preserved. Below is an example from `4-D` array and the slicing results.

```
In [327]: xa
Out[327]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        [[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]]],


       [[[18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26]],

        [[27, 28, 29],
         [30, 31, 32],
         [33, 34, 35]]]])

In [328]: xa[0, 0, :, [0, 1]]
Out[328]: 
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [1, 4, 7]])

In [329]: xa[0, 0, :, 0:2]
Out[329]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are actually using [*advanced indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) when you use `[0,1]`. From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing):

> #### Combining advanced and basic indexing
>
> When there is at least one
>   slice (`:`), ellipsis (`...`) or `np.newaxis` in the index (or the array has
>   more dimensions than there are advanced indexes), then the behaviour
>   can be more complicated. **It is like concatenating the indexing result
>   for each advanced index element**
>
> In the simplest case, there is only a single advanced index. **A single
>   advanced index can for example replace a slice and the result array
>   will be the same, however, it is a copy and may have a different
>   memory layout**. A slice is preferable when it is possible.

Pay attention to the two parts I've bolded above.

In particular, in this construction:

```
>>> x[0,:,[0,1]]
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Is the case where there is at least once "slice, ellipsisi, or np.newaxis" in the index, and the behavior is like **concatenating the indexing result for each advanced index element**. So:

```
>>> x[0,:,[0]]
array([[1, 2]])
>>> x[0,:,[1]]
array([[1, 2]])
>>> np.concatenate((x[0,:,[0]], x[0,:,[1]]))
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

However, this construction is like the simple case: there is only a single advanced index, so it acts like a slice:

```
>>> x[0,:,slice(2)]
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
>>> x[slice(0,1),:,slice(2)]
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

Although note, that the later is actually *three dimensional* because the first part of the index acted as a slice, it's 3 slices so three dimensions.

Comment: It seems like your answer is missing its last part, was there something supposed to follow "Similarly," ?

Comment: Thank you, juanpa.arrivillaga. Numpy should be styled more functional, in the meaning of optimization.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207850/numpy-sub-array-assignment-with-advanced-mixed-indexing I found links to bug/issues for the case of `[scalar, slice, list]` indexing.  For more SO discussions, search on '[numpy] advanced-and-basic-indexing'.