# Implicit transposing in numpy array indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I came across a weird problem:

```
from numpy import zeros, arange
aa = zeros([1, 3, 10])
aa[0, :, arange(5)].shape
```

Running this gives me `(5,3)`, but I'm expecting `(3,5)`.

However, running the following gives me `(3,5)` as expected.

```
aa = zeros([3, 10])
aa[:, arange(5)]
```

This is easy to fix as part of my program, but it completely ruined my belief.

I tried to search for similar questions that have already been answered but have no idea what to search for.

Thank you and Happy Chinese New Year!

Answer (score 5):

This is a case of mixed basic and advanced indexing.  The 1st and last indexes are numeric, and the middle a slice.  It selects values based the `0` and `arange(5)`, and appends the `:` dimension at the end.

```
aa[0, :, :5].shape
```

should produce the (3,5) you expect.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

[Numpy 3D array transposed when indexed in single step vs two steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016092/numpy-3d-array-transposed-when-indexed-in-single-step-vs-two-steps)  contrasts the behavior of

```
y = x[0, :, mask]
z = x[0, :, :][:, mask]
```

Be sure to check the comments to my answer, for the argument that this is a bug and will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But for the last line, are you saying this is a bug and the developers are considering to fix it, or probably many people would consider it as a bug?