# Indexing multidimensional Numpy array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Consider the following numpy array.

```
a = np.random.randn(10, 3, 20)
```

When I index the array as follow, it produces another array with expected shape

```
b = a[0, :, 0:5]
b.shape = (3, 5)
```

But when I index it with another numpy array but with similar elements,  it produces a different array, which is transpose of the above result.

```
j = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
b = a[0, :, j]
b.shape = (5, 3)
```

I couldn't understand why this is the case.

Comment: Quite interesting. I'm observing this behaviour as well, but I'm not enough of a numpy expert to understand the cause. I'll poke around and see if I can determine more.

Comment: It's subtle.  The second example is concatenating a set of slices.  If you print `a[0,:,0]`, you'll see a 3-element slice, equal to the first row of the final `b`.  Same with `a[0,:,1]`.  The magic indexing takes those 5 3-element slices and returns then in a new array.  A set of 5 slices is different from the array subset in `a[0,:,0:5]`.

Comment: So it seems like both versions are actually just tranposed version of the eachother.

Comment: I would love to mark this reply as an accepted answer.

Comment: Isn't this still the implicit transposing of mixed indexing 'bug'? Compare `a[0, :, j]` vs `a[0][:,j]` discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306427/14277722) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020886/14277722)

Comment: @Habtie27 I included Tim's writup and an observation of my own in an answer. Feel free to check it out :)

Comment: @Michael I agree that it is extremely unintuitive, at least.

Comment: @richardec Thanks! I accepted  it as a valid answer.

Comment: Mixed advanced and basic indexing bites again :)  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

Comment: @hpaulj I suspected if it was something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) summarized it excellently in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489032/indexing-multidimensional-numpy-array-with-another-array#comment126355601_71489032), which I'll quote here in case the comments are cleaned up:

> It's subtle. The second example is concatenating a set of slices. If you print `a[0,:,0]`, you'll see a 3-element slice, equal to the first row of the final b. Same with `a[0,:,1]`. The magic indexing takes those 5 3-element slices and returns then in a new array. A set of 5 slices is different from the array subset in `a[0,:,0:5]`.

In addition, if you notice, the two different indexing methods actually produce equivalent results; they're just transposed versions of each other. So `a[0, :, np.arange(5)] == a[0, :, 0:5].T` and `a[0, :, np.arange(5)].T == a[0, :, 0:5]`.