# Why does numpy transpose the result in some cases when indexing with a boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have some trouble understanding the behaviour of numpy when indexing a multi-dimensional array (d >= 3) with a boolean mask along one dimension.

The following example makes sense to me:

```
> x = np.zeros((2, 2, 3))
> mask = np.ones(3, dtype=bool)
> print(x[:,:,:].shape)

(2, 2, 3)

> print(x[:,:,mask].shape)

(2, 2, 3)
```

But this examples does not make sense to me:

```
> x = np.zeros((2, 2, 3))
> mask = np.ones(3, dtype=bool)
> print(x[0,:,:].shape)

(2, 3)

> print(x[0,:,mask].shape)

(3, 2)
```

It appears that the result is transposed in the second case of the last example. Why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020886/17457846

Comment: @HMH1013 It is somewhat comforting that, apparently, even the numpy developers consider this behaviour a bit extreme. =)

Comment: Using the mask is the same as using `np.array([0,1,2])`, and yes this is the documented mixed basic and advanced indexing.